# Find the given file path is valid in ios?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am trying to create a class which has a method that receives a file path(NSString) as parameter.

I need to check the given file path is valid if it is valid I will do some writing operation on disk otherwise I ll return error.

So is it any best way to find out the given path is valid one?

Comment: What do you mean by a valid path? One containing no illegal characters or one that may be written to as well?

Comment: @paul I don't mean illegal character like /^# etc. I am expecting that the user has correctly given the path like /var/mobile/Applications/8EFCBF99-BC19-4AFE-934A-B47CBEDF2971/Documents/fileName. Because the function receives NSString as argument. So I need to check that is it correctly points the sand box. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to check first if path is valid. Just go ahead and try to create it and then check for success.

**createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:** method of **NSFileManager** returns a **BOOL** that returns YES if the file already exists or did succeed in creating it.

I suggest using this method and check the returned result. If it returns NO then return error.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

For your example this would return

> /var/mobile/Applications/8EFCBF99-BC19-4AFE-934A-B47CBEDF2971/Documents

Does that help you? I think the method is included in the AppDelegate of all Xcode project types that use Core Data.

Here is an example:

```
NSString *validPath = [[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"];
NSString *invalidPath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/abc/test";

if (0 == [validPath rangeOfString:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path]].location) {
    // will be executed
    NSLog(@"Valid path");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid path");
}

if (0 == [invalidPath rangeOfString:[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] path]].location) {
    NSLog(@"Valid path");
}
else {
    // will be executed
    NSLog(@"Invalid path");
}
```

Comment: How do validate full path(with filename or ValidFilPathUptoDocument/Your...Folder/_!%@#df_FileName")? That's question here, I think.

Comment: @paul If the user gives the file path which is generated from this method then it is good for me. But if the user gives the some string like "fhdajkfal" it is any possible to find out the path pointing to sandbox?

Comment: He asked for a method that tells him the path to the sandbox (see comment to the question). He did not specify if he expects a file or if he just wanted to make sure the file path lies within the sandbox.

Comment: I am not down voting paul

Comment: I upvoted you again, don't see why your answer is not useful.